# rxjs switchMap type mismatch issue

Tags: angular, rxjs, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a typeahead with ng-bootstrap in my app.  I'm following the  [wikipedia example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#http) where it fetches data using the WikipediaService.

I've implemented something similar in my app, but I'm having a type mismatch issue within the `switchMap` function from `rxjs`.

**Example from ng-bootstrap:**

```typescript
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(() => this.searching = true),
    switchMap(term =>
      this._service.search(term).pipe(
        tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
        catchError(() => {
          this.searchFailed = true;
          return of([]);
        }))
    ),
    tap(() => this.searching = false)
  )
```

My issue is that when I try to implement this, `term` within `switchMap` is an `Observable<{}>` rather than a `string`, so I'm unable to pass it to my service.

How do I get the actual value from the observable to pass to my service?

**My version:**

```typescript
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(() => this.searching = true),
    switchMap(term =>
      this.placeService.search(term).pipe(  // [ts] Argument of type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. 
        tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
        catchError(() => {
          this.searchFailed = true;
          return of([]);
        })
    ),
    tap(() => this.searching = false))
  )
```

**Update 1**

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prm3rm).  If you look on `app\app.component.ts`, you get the TS linting error.

Comment: @trichetriche I've reproduced it on StackBlitz, see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prm3rm

Comment: It doesn't reproduce your issue ... Try reproducing it !

Comment: @trichetriche it does? It takes several seconds for it to show up once it's been loaded, but you get the issue.  I get "Argument of type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'."

Comment: Well for me it's `ERROR
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> PlaceService]`

Comment: Oh you mean as a TSLint error ?

Comment: Yup - that's preventing my build from working locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comments, you had a parenthesis issue. [Here it is, working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prm3rm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

```js
/*
  Observables are streams that can be monitored. It means that when you 
  subscribe to it, everytime a value is emitted, your subscribe function 
  will be triggered (or in this case, the pipe functions, because you
  subscribe to search() in another component)
*/
search(text$: Observable<string>) {
  return text$
    // pipe = perform operations on the value before sending it to subscribe
    .pipe(
      // debounceTime = wait 300ms before emitting. If a new value is emitted,
      // cancel the previous one
      debounceTime(300),
      // distinctUntilChanged = if the value is the same as the previous one, cancel
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      // tap = perform an operation without touching the value emitted
      tap(() => this.searching = true),
      // switchMap = cancel previous HTTP requests if they're not finished
      switchMap(term => this.placeService.search(term).pipe(
      tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
      // catchError = self-explanatory :)
      catchError(() => {
        this.searchFailed = true;
        return of([]);
      })
    )),
      tap(() => this.searching = false)
    )
};
```

Comment: Well I can comment the code if you want quick explanations ?

Comment: If you've got time, sure.  I find the rxjs documentation lacking.

Comment: @Tom done ! If I can be of any advice, I would suggest you learn Angular before RxJS, since the Angular documentation explains a lot of RxJS behaviors.

Comment: The comments are a great help, they actually make a tonne of sense in the context of being used with the Typeahead control too.  I've only just started using ng this week, so I should really get stuck into the docs at some point!

Comment: @Tom if you get stuck on something, don't hesitate to keep reading further. Many times I had the same issue, and I got unstuck just by reading the next steps (for instance, I couldn't understand custom input validators, but after reading the whole page, I started seeing how to use them). Good luck !